# Multiple ng-model from one ng

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

Dear all I am creating a checkbox where it will show the name of multiple item with its price, user can choose what he/she wants. In ng-model I need both the name of the item and the price. Here is one sample code I found.

```
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label>
        <input ng-model="data[item.name + '||' + item.price]" type="checkbox" id="{{item.id}}">
        {{item.name}} with {{item.price | currency}}
      </label>
    </div>
```

And later on used string splitter to get the values. Is there any way I can get item.name and item.price using two different ng-model ?

Comment: your question isn't really clear; instead of presenting someone else's code and asking how to change it, you should present your actual data so that it's clear what you are trying to represent.

Comment: Lets say this is my actual data.

Comment: there isn't actually any data here or information how you are consuming said data, you presented a code snippet that someone else wrote that  relies upon an `item` object which has multiple properties, which seems to concatenate the properties for no reason, and ask how to keep the properties separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, You cannot use 2 ng-models for the same element, it does not make any sense as well.

Just set `ng-model` as a property on the item say `selected`

```
<input ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" id="{{item.id}}">
```

and since the item object itself has a price and name you can easily filter out the items `selected` and its respective name and price.

ex:

```
var selectedItems = $scope.items.filter(function(itm){return itm.selected});
```

If you want to set `ngmodel` as id with value as item properties (the way you have in your question) you could as well use `ng-true-value` (Though i think the previous approach should just suffice).

```
<input ng-model="data[item.id]" ng-true-value="{{item.name + '||' + item.price}}" type="checkbox" id="{{item.id}}">
```